# Creating a custom countdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, countdown

So I am creating a custom page opening countdown and I am wondering how do I create the JavaScript part?

This is my JavaScript

```
function start() {
    var openDate = new Date(2013, 7, 24);
    setInterval(function () {
        var today = new Date();
        var delta = openDate - today;
        var days = Math.floor(delta / 86400).toString();
        var hours = (Math.floor(delta / 3600) % 24).toString();
        var minutes = (Math.floor(delta / 60) % 60).toString();
        var seconds = (delta % 60).toString();

        $(".seconds#first").text(seconds[0]);

    }, 1000);
}
```

This works, but the values are off. I don't know what to do. This is my HTML also if it helps.

```
<div id="countdown">
    <ul class="days">
        <li id="first">1</li>
        <li id="second">1</li>
        <li id="third">1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="hours">
        <li id="first">1</li>
        <li id="second">1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="minutes">
        <li id="first">1</li>
        <li id="second">1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="last" class="seconds">
        <li id="first">1</li>
        <li id="second">1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check that the timezone is correct?  What do you mean by "The values are off"?

Comment: Every Time it goes past the seconds will be like. 39, 49,5, 2, 5. It seems like it is just random values.

Comment: The sample code contains many obvious errors and does not work at all (e.g., the `start` function is not called at all, there are multiple elements with the same `id` attribute). The question does not specify what the countdown should actually do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you subtract two date values in JavaScript, the returned value is always in milliseconds. This means that the value of the variable `delta` would be in milliseconds and that is what was causing the issue as the rest of your code is written with the assumption that the return value is in seconds.

To overcome this, the `delta` value should be divided by 1000 (to convert it to seconds) and the `Math.floor` function should be used in the calculation of the seconds value also because millisecond to seconds conversion could result in fractional values.

```js
var openDate = new Date(2015, 7, 24);

setInterval(function () {

    var today = new Date();
    var delta = (openDate - today) / 1000; //to convert to seconds
    var days = Math.floor(delta / 86400).toString();
    var hours = (Math.floor(delta / 3600) % 24).toString();
    var minutes = (Math.floor(delta / 60) % 60).toString();
    var seconds = (Math.floor(delta % 60)).toString();

    document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = "Days: " + days + "  Time: " + hours + " : " + minutes + " : " + seconds;

}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="first"></div>
```

[JavaScript Date Object - MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)